# p-confirmDialog is not getting focused

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, primeng, confirm-dialog

Whenever I click on the button, dialogbox is opening but the whole screen greys out and I cannot click on the dialogbox.

.html file

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle">
```

```
<button type="text" (click)="confirm()" pButton icon="pi pi-check" 
label="Confirm"></button>
```

.ts file

```
constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {}

confirm() {
this.confirmationService.confirm({
    message: 'Are you sure that you want to perform this action?',
    accept: () => {
        //Actual logic to perform a confirmation
    }
});
}
```

[click here to see how the dialogbox is rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b7G2.png)

Comment: Once try appendTo option and check the result. `<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" [appendTo]="body"></p-confirmDialog>`

Comment: This worked.Thanks!